# CSS / Bootstrap 3: remove styling from links

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, anchor

I am trying to remove styling from links (anchor tags) in the following lines so that the links appear with black color and no underlining by default. For some reason my CSS class ("`deco-none`") is ignored here and they still appear in blue as normal links (I am using IE9 and Bootstrap 3).

What do I have to change here ?

**My HTML:**

```
<div class="row" style="width:400px;">
    <ul class="list-unstyled col-md-4">
        <li class="bg-menu clickable"><a href="#" class="deco-none">test1-1</a></li>
        <li class="bg-menu clickable"><a href="#" class="deco-none">test1-2</a></li>
        <li class="bg-menu clickable"><a href="#" class="deco-none">test1-3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="list-unstyled col-md-4">
        <li class="bg-menu clickable"><a href="#" class="deco-none">test2-1</a></li>
        <li class="bg-menu clickable"><a href="#" class="deco-none">test2-2</a></li>
        <li class="bg-menu clickable"><a href="#" class="deco-none">test2-3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="list-unstyled col-md-4">
        <li class="bg-menu clickable"><a href="#" class="deco-none">test3-1</a></li>
        <li class="bg-menu clickable"><a href="#" class="deco-none">test3-2</a></li>
        <li class="bg-menu clickable"><a href="#" class="deco-none">test3-3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**My CSS:**

```
a.deco-none: {
    color:#000000 !important;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.bg-menu:hover {
    background-color:#0079C1;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}

.clickable {
    cursor:pointer; 
}
```

Comment: you have a typo in your class name.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Bootstrap

Comment: This can be closed as "typo".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You got it wrong in CSS. Try this

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/richasingh/ffqgm9n1/3/)**

```
a.deco-none {
    color:#000000 !important;
    text-decoration:none;

}

.bg-menu:hover {
    background-color:#0079C1;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}

.clickable {
    cursor:pointer; 
}
```

**Below code is wrong**

```
a.deco-none: {
    color:#000000 !important;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: Oh dear, you are right - beginner mistake. :) Thanks for that - will accept as soon as I can.

Comment: Happens with everyone :) And glad to have helped :)

Comment: For other people who were staring at the wrong code, trying to figure out what was wrong: there's a colon `:` after `a.deco-none:`, which shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 9):

To make it complete (does not change colour on hover or after clicking it and inherits `text-decoration`, too):

```
.deco-none {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: inherit;
}

.deco-none:link {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: inherit;
}

.deco-none:hover {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: inherit;
}
```

#### Example Snippet

```css
.deco-none {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: inherit;
}
.deco-none:link {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: inherit;
}
.deco-none:hover {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: inherit;
}
.bg-menu:hover {
  background-color: #0079C1;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.clickable {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row" style="width:400px;">
  <ul class="list-unstyled col-md-4">
    <li class="bg-menu clickable"><a href="#" class="deco-none">test1-1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="bg-menu clickable"><a href="#" class="deco-none">test1-2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="bg-menu clickable"><a href="#" class="deco-none">test1-3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list-unstyled col-md-4">
    <li class="bg-menu clickable"><a href="#" class="deco-none">test2-1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="bg-menu clickable"><a href="#" class="deco-none">test2-2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="bg-menu clickable"><a href="#" class="deco-none">test2-3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list-unstyled col-md-4">
    <li class="bg-menu clickable"><a href="#" class="deco-none">test3-1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="bg-menu clickable"><a href="#" class="deco-none">test3-2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="bg-menu clickable"><a href="#" class="deco-none">test3-3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest to use the `inherit` keyword to inherit the parents color. I know you wanted them black, but I'm sure that other users will find it helpful.

```
a.deco-none {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

as [Dimitry K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1168382/dimitry-k) said, you had the `a.deco-none:` typo.